# django - model foreign key as logged user

Tags: python, django

I've got model code as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings

class Doc(models.Model):
...
added_by = models.CharField(blank=False,null=True,max_length=100,validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
added_by_2 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

I can migrate this without any problems, but every when I run server and in admin site try to view all records I get:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: no such column: added_by_2_id
```

What is the cause of this error? How to resolve it?

Comment: Looks like you did not make migrations/migrated properly. Are you sure you made migrations up to the last version of your model, and *migrated* the database with these migrations?

Comment: After changes in model I've done: python manage.py makemigrations then python manage.py migrate

Comment: should I do anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `null=True` option on your `added_by_2` field declaration, so Django can store empty values as `NULL` in the database.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#null) for more info

Comment: thx. You don't even know how much you've helped me. I just couldn't figure this out. The error log is confusing.